# Golang. Как распараллелить обработку слайса, чтобы получить выигрышь в скорости?

Tags: многопоточность, golang, concurrency, распараллеливание

Есть слайс, содержащий большое количество элементов, допустим 100000. Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая умножит каждый элемент данного слайcа на 2. **Я хочу, чтобы эта функция работала конкурентно и имела выигрыш в скорости по сравнению с функцией, делающей тоже самое последовательно.**

Последовательная функция:

```
func doubleSlice(s []int) {
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = s[i] * 2
    }
}
```

Конкурентный вариант:

```
func concurentDoubleSlice(s []int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := range s {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            s[i] = s[i] * 2
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Я прочтал, что данный вариант будет замедлять программу из-за большого количество вызываемых горутин и сборщика мусора. Также я прочитал, что данная проблема может быть решена с помощью буферизированного  канала, но реализовать его и получить выигрышь в скорости мне не удоалось.

**Как я могу ускорить процесс умножения элементов слайса, с помощью конкурентности?**

Comment: Вам надо разделить слайс на какое-то разумное число частей (скажем, на 20) и каждую из частей обработать в отдельной go-рутине.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разбить массив не на 100000 частей (как это сейчас сделано с точностью до элемента), а две, три или десять:

0 - 9999, 10000 - 19999 и т.д.

и каждую часть обработайте отдельной гороутиной.
Достаточно выделить непересекающиеся диапазоны индексов в массиве.

UPD:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const size = 100000000

func main() {

    for i := 20; i > 0; i-- {

        debug.SetGCPercent(-1)

        src := make([]int, size)

        for idx := range src {
            src[idx] = 42
        }

        fmt.Println("до    ", src[:4], src[size-4:])
        t1 := time.Now()
        multiply2(src, i)
        dur := time.Since(t1)
        fmt.Println("после ", src[:4], src[size-4:])
        fmt.Printf("число гороутин: %d, время: %s\n", i, dur)
        fmt.Println()

        runtime.GC()

    }
}

func multiply2(src []int, workers int) {

    if workers <= 0 {
        return
    }
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    last := 0

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {

        idx1 := len(src) / workers * i
        idx2 := len(src) / workers * (i + 1)
        last = idx2

        wg.Add(1)
        go func(idx1, idx2 int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for idx := idx1; idx < idx2; idx++ {
                src[idx] = src[idx] * 2
            }
        }(idx1, idx2)

    }

    if last < len(src)-1 {
        idx1 := last
        idx2 := len(src)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(idx1, idx2 int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for idx := idx1; idx < idx2; idx++ {
                src[idx] = src[idx] * 2
            }
        }(idx1, idx2)
    }

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я написал таким образом 2 программы и получил выигрышь в 300 микро секунд. на 1000000000 элементах. У моего процессора имеется 8 ядер. Разве такая прибавка к скорости не является минимальной? Более того, я использовал данный код в более большой программе - основной целью было улучшить ее производительность и там я проивзодительность потерял на 3-4 секнуды.

Какой наилучший способ реализовывать метод, который вы описали? Я пользовался каналами. Это верный подход?

Comment: Думаю при таких размерах слайса тормоза могут возникать по совершенно другим причинам, например 1000000000 int32 это примерно 4GB? Возможно он даже не целиком помещается в оперативную память. Добавил код как бы я сделал. Просто дал разным гороутинам доступ к разным частям слайса и дождался выполнения всех. Оптимальное количество зависит от железа. У меня выполнение в одном потоке стабильно дает самый медленный результат, примерно на 30%. От 2 до 20 потоков время выполнения скачет но принципиально не меняется.

Comment: На этом примере я и правда получаю выигрышь. Но я решил воспользоваться данным подходом в своей основной задаче и я получаю сильный провал в скорости. https://dropmefiles.com/n5rJT. Я выложил 2 файла сюда, они в формате .html. 

Эти два файла отличаются тем, что в файле gocode.html я попробывал реализовать ваш метод. Я сделал это в 2 местах.
1) после комментария "//деление эелементов текущей строки..."
2) после комментария "//вычитание текущей сктроки из.."

после добавленя конкурентности в пункт 1 я получаю несильный провал в скорости, но он есть. Во втором пункте провал в 3-4 секунды